# ConcurrentHashMap: Using merge() on a nested concurrentHashMap in Java

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I have a concurrentHashMap like this:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long>> hashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>()
```

I need to update the nested hashmap's value based on the current value if already present. I was currently doing something like this:

```
 if (hashMap.containsKey("key")) {

        long count = (hashMap.get("key").containsKey(longKey)) ?
                    (hashMap.get("key").get(longKey) + 1l) :
                    1l;

        hashMap.put("key", new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long>() {{
            put(longKey, count);
        }});
    }
```

Basically, check if "key" is present, then check if longKey is present in the nested concurrentHashMap and if yes, all 1l to the existing value. Else, put 1l. If "key" not present, create a new concurrentHashMap with new values.

How can I use merge method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction- to do the same? Because I want get and update  to be atomic.

Comment: Note that your example code is _far_ from thread safe. The `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't help you here. And using the notorious "double brace initialisation" is an absolutely **awful** idea - even more so than usually. You are created a new anonymous class for each sub-`Map`.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please let me know how I can make it thread-safe?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, thank for pointing that out! Edited it

Comment: @BoristheSpider He's creating a single anonymous class, though all instances inside his `hashMap` are of that anonymous subclass, which I agree is quite bad.

Comment: Is the key to the inner ConcurrentMap suppose to be Long or String?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight fair point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand the problem, you can do this in a thread-safe manner using the following code:

```
Map<Long, Long> longMap =
    hashMap.computeIfAbsent("key", k -> new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
longMap.merge(longKey, 1L, Long::sum);
```

You should seriously consider just using plain synchronization. Plain synchronization is much, much easier to get right if you are inexperienced at writing thread-safe code. If you use a [`Collections.synchronizedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-), for example, you can just do `synchronized (map) {...}` any time you need to do more than a single method call.

Comment: What Boris said. Especially `Long::sum` :-)